# Nodejs error in Heroku: H12 "Request Timeout"

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs backend deployed on Heroku to handle the communication between a Telegram bot and some APIs. The problem is the bot sometimes takes hours to send some response back and I get continuos errors like the this (sometimes, every 1 minute):

```
heroku[router]: - at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/new-message" host=MY_APP request_id=SOME_ID fwd="SOME_ADDRESS" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

And my code (in index.js) is as follows:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const axios = require('axios');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.post('/new-message', function(req, res) {
  const {message} = req.body

  if (!message) {
    return res.end()
  }

  if (message.text === 'Hello world!') {
    axios.post('https://api.telegram.org/botID/sendMessage', {
      chat_id: message.chat.id,
      text: 'You said Hello world!'
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Message posted');
        res.end('ok');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error :', err);
        res.end('Error :' + err);
      })
  } 
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

The error not only happens when I write a "Hello world!" message, but also without doing anything. And in some cases, the bot replies me correctly, but that is not the general rule... In some cases, I even receive the response the day after.

Any idea of what the problem could be? I guess it's a problem related to being waiting for a response and after 30 seconds giving an error back, but I don't know how to fix it...

Thanks a lot!